# When was the power restored?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, time

The power went out last night. The stove clock is flickering and showing 7:54 AM. The cell phone shows 7:07 AM.  When was the power restored?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Presuming the stove

> reset to 12:00 midnight when power was restored and ran normally from there, power was restored 7 hours and 54 minutes ago, at 11:13 PM.

Comment: Thanks!  Makes it look easy. Was thinking in terms of : if the clock is x minutes ahead, then it started x minutes before midnight, when power came back. ... Great!